# Haskell: Nested monad error with STM writeTVar

Tags: haskell

I have the following code

```hs
module MyLib (write) where

import Control.Monad.STM
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TVar

write :: STM (TVar Störm) -> Störm -> IO ()
write state' new = atomically $ write' state'
      where
        write' :: STM (TVar Störm) -> STM ()
        write' state' = write'' <$> state'
        write'' :: TVar Störm -> STM ()
        write'' state' = writeTVar state' new
```

Using the dependency STM

I am getting the following error

```
src/MyLib.hs:39:25: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘STM ()’ with ‘()’
      Expected: TVar Störm -> ()
        Actual: TVar Störm -> STM ()
    • In the first argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘write''’
      In the expression: write'' <$> state'
      In an equation for ‘write'’: write' state' = write'' <$> state'
   |
39 |         write' state' = write'' <$> state'
```

Which for my testing it is nesting the Monads to `STM (STM ())`. And have no idea how to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in here term `write'' <$> state'`. In this context, `(<$>)` has type:

```
(<$>) :: (TVar Störm -> STM ()) -> STM (TVar Störm) -> STM (STM ())
```

and

```
write'' <$> state' :: STM (STM ())
```

but expected type is `STM ()`.

To fix that, you can do:

```
join $ write'' <$> state'
```

But simpler will be:

```
write'' =<< state'
```

or:

```
state' >>= write''
```

---

However, I would write like this:

```
write :: STM (TVar Störm) -> Störm -> IO ()
write action new = atomically $ do
    var <- action
    writeTVar var new
```